# Flash iOS textfield input autoSize

Tags: iphone, flash, actionscript-3, ios5

I want the width and height from the textfield to be set automatically.
But if I use:

```
textField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.RIGHT;
```

It runs perfectly on the computer. But if I transfer the app to my iPhone and I test it, the textfield turns in the size of one character so the rest I'm typing scrolls out of the textfield area. It's pretty hard to explain what happens, but it just looks like it doesn't set the height and width the right way. And even if I use the

```
textField.scrollV = 0;
```

it keeps scrolling.

I've tried to explain it as much as I can, thanks in advanced!

With kind regards,
Tim

Comment: is this an inputfield? i've never used `autoSize` on an inputfield - that's not really what this is for.

Answer (score 0):

"Use device fonts" for Anti-alias.